# c# sqlite query

Tags: c#, database, sqlite

C# SQLite Query

```
String sql = @"SELECT user FROM '" + channel + "' ORDER BY currency DESC LIMIT 10";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem with your query. The SELECT extracts only one column from the table represented by the variable `channel`. So your `GetString(1)` in the reader loop fails because there is no field at index 1 (arrays start at index zero). You need to change that GetString index.

Then there is a problem in the return value. You say that you want to return a single string but there is no return statement and you don't have any single string to return

You could write

```
public string top10()
{
    List<string> toplist = new List<string>();
    String sql = "SELECT user FROM '" + channel + "' ORDER BY currency DESC LIMIT 10";
    using (cmd = new SQLiteCommand(sql, myDB))
    {
        using (SQLiteDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (r.Read())
            {
                 toplist.Add(r.GetString(0));
            }
        }
    }
    return string.Join(",", toplist);
}
```

or change the return type of the method to

```
public List<string> top10()
{
   .....
   return toplist;
}
```

or to

```
public string[] top10()
{
   .....
   return toplist.ToArray();
}
```

I have changed your internal array to a `List<string>` because if you have less than 10 records your array will have empty strings instead a list will return just the rows found.

Comment: Adding with Steve answer please use parameter with dynamic query. please follow this link for more on this. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx

Comment: @NitinAggarwal unfortunately you can't use parameters for tablenames.

Comment: Thanks Steve! If you are still here, can you please show me how I can return a user rank? For example, it will order by currency and it will return the row of a certain user (aka rank). Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

You may also try this answer.

```
    public string getTop10()
    {
        List<string> Toplist = new List<string>();
        string connection = "YourConnectionString";
        using (var con = new SQLiteConnection { ConnectionString = connection })
        {
            using (var command = new SQLiteCommand { Connection = con })
            {
                con.Open();

                command.CommandText = @"SELECT user FROM @channel ORDER BY currency DESC LIMIT 10";
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@channel", channel);
                using (var r = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while(r.Read())
                    {
                        Toplist.Add(r.GetString(0));
                    }

                }

            }

        }
        return string.Join(",", Toplist);
    }
```